Why is the Vietoris–Rips complex $\operatorname{VR}(S, \epsilon)$ a subset of the Čech complex $\operatorname{Čech}(S, \epsilon\sqrt{2})$?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Cech{Čech}\DeclareMathOperator\VR{VR}$I am reading Fasy, Lecci, Rinaldo, Wasserman, Balakrishnan, and Singh - Confidence sets for persistence diagrams (see here for a version of the paper with appendix) for an undergraduate reading project on persistent homology. In Appendix A.2 of the paper, the authors mention this sandwich relation for Vietoris–Rips and Čech complexes:
$$\Cech(S, \epsilon) \subseteq \VR(S, \epsilon) \subseteq \Cech(S, \epsilon \sqrt{2}).$$
Please see below for the conventions regarding the variables and complexes.
The fact that $\Cech(S, \epsilon) \subseteq \VR(S, \epsilon)$ is trivial enough, but  may someone explain to me the proof of $\VR(S, \epsilon) \subseteq \Cech(S, \epsilon \sqrt{2})$?
Here are the conventions I am using:

$S$ is a finite point cloud (of cardinality $n+1$) embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$\epsilon \geq 0$,
$\VR(S, \epsilon)$ is the Vietoris–Rips complex such that a set $\{v_0, v_1, \dotsc, v_n\}$ is a simplex in $\VR(S, \epsilon)$ if and only if the Euclidean distance between any two $v_i, v_j$ is $\leq 2\epsilon$, and
$\Cech(S, \epsilon \sqrt{2})$ is the Čech complex such that a set $\{v_0, v_1, \dotsc, v_n\}$ is a simplex in $\Cech(S, \epsilon\sqrt{2})$ if and only if the closed balls centered around each $v_i$ with radius $\epsilon\sqrt{2}$ have a nonempty intersection.


Since it did not seem important that you were accessing this arXiv paper through ResearchGate, I changed the link to point to the source (the arXiv).  I hope that that was all right.

@LSpice: Thanks for the edit, but I was trying to refer to a page in the appendix of the paper, and I do not know if it is accessible from the arXiv version of the paper.

Re, I am not familiar with the conventions for such papers; I suspect it is in the linked "Supplementary material" of v3.  But ResearchGate says that they got the paper from the arXiv (although, if so, they parasitically stripped the watermark), and v2 seems to be identical to the ResearchGate version, so I edited again to link to that.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cech{Čech}\DeclareMathOperator\VR{VR}$
I'm the OP. Much thanks to @alesia for pointing me to Jung's Theorem; I have a valid proof now.
The inclusion $\VR(S, \epsilon) \subseteq \Cech(S, \epsilon \sqrt{2})$ is equivalent to the following statement:

"For any $\{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\} \subseteq S$, if $\{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ forms a simplex in $\VR(S, \epsilon)$, then $\{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ forms a simplex in $\Cech(S, \epsilon \sqrt{2})$."

Which is again equivalent to

"For any $\{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\} \subseteq S$, if $d(v_i, v_j):= \|v_i- v_j\|_2 \leq 2\epsilon$ then the union of closed balls $\bigcap_{i=0}^{n} B(v_i, \epsilon \sqrt{2}) \neq \varnothing$."

Suppose that $\{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\} \subseteq S$ and $\|v_i, v_j\|_2 \leq 2\epsilon$. Then $d := 2\epsilon$ is the diameter of the set $\{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$. By Jung's Theorem, there exists a point $c$ and radius $r \leq d \sqrt{\frac{n}{2(n+1)}} = \epsilon \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ such that the closed ball $B(c, r) \supseteq \{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$. This implies that $d(v_i, c):= \|v_i-c\| \leq r \leq \epsilon \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} < \epsilon \sqrt{2}$ for any $v_i \in \{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$. Hence for any $v_i \in \{v_0,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$, the closed ball $B(v_i, \epsilon\sqrt{2})$ always contains the point $c$. Hence $c \in \bigcap_{i=0}^{n} B(v_i, \epsilon \sqrt{2})$, implying $\bigcap_{i=0}^{n} B(v_i, \epsilon \sqrt{2}) \neq \varnothing$.

@LSpice: And thank you very much too for helping me with formatting!
